# PHP WebSocket SSL

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, encryption

I am trying to upgrade my PHP WebSocket library to SSL, using the `wss://`-protocol on the client-side. However, I find myself at a loss trying to figure out a) how to set up the server socket, and b) how to decode the incoming messages. Here is my current attempt at the former:

```
$context = stream_context_create();

// local_cert must be in PEM format
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pemFilePath);
// Pass Phrase (password) of private key
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pemPassPhrase);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

$serverSocket = stream_socket_server('ssl://'.$host.':'.$port, $errNo, $errStr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);
```

However, when using SSL as the server protocol, the client does not seem to be sending any messages, and when using tcp, I get weird, encrypted data, although it was my guess that it would be magically decrypted due to my providing the options to the stream context.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem with our implementation, and found a good workaround. Put your websocket server on any firewalled port, and tunnel connections from a secure port port. You can use [stunnel](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/stunnel-universal-ssl-tunnel-for-network-daemons.html) with a configuration like this:

```
[websockets]
accept = 8443
connect = 8080
```

This way, stunnel does all the security, and your websocket server does all the websockets. Win!